# How to create a QML component from C++ with component scope instance hierarchy

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a test QML file like this:

```
// TestMain.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    width: G_WIDTH
    height: G_HEIGHT

    readonly property real x_SCALE: width / G_WIDTH
    readonly property real y_SCALE: height / G_HEIGHT

    title: "Test Window"
    visible: true

    Item {
        id: wrapper

        anchors.fill: parent

        <innerItem>
    }
}
```

And I want to dynamically create and assign the `innerItem` at runtime from C++ (I am trying to setup a testing framework). Here is what I have in C++:

```
engine->load("TestMain.qml");
if (engine->rootObjects().isEmpty()) { // Error }

auto root = engine->rootObjects().first();
auto wrapper = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(main->children()[1]);
QQmlComponent component(engine.get(), "ComponentToBeTested.qml");
auto item = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(component.createWithInitialProperties(props));
item->setParentItem(wrapper);
item->setSize(wrapper->size());

app->exec();
```

But `ComponentToBeTested` doesn't seem to be able to see `x_SCALE` and `y_SCALE` defined in `TestMain`. What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems you have an XY problem. The properties are only accessible within the scope of the file, that is, x_SCALE and Y_SCALE are only accessible in TestMain.qml.

Comment: @eyllanesc That is not true. If `InnerItem {}` was another file but added to the TestMain.qml it would have been able to see properties of all its ancestors. Regardless of if it is defined in the same file or not.

Comment: Each .qml is a black box where you can only see the properties, signals and functions of the root. This implies that the .qml "child" will not meet the .qml "parent"

Comment: TestMain.qml can use the properties of the root item of ComponentToBeTested.qml but not vice versa

Comment: It would be interesting if you show the example where other elements of .qml are accessible in the way you indicate. The properties of a .qml are not global unless they are singletons or context-properties exposed from C++

Comment: @eyllanesc
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html#component-instance-hierarchy
> The component instance scope hierarchy extends to out-of-line components, too.

Comment: I already gave you my vision, from my experience with QML, it is not possible to access the properties of a parent .qml in a child .qml (if the parent-child term is valid). The concept of .qml is like having a reusable box so it has its own scope for this. Without further evidence I will not point out anything else.

Comment: In the first link the scope of the objects is the same, they are not 2 different qml (files). Same for the second.

Comment: @eyllanesc What more evidence do you want than the Qt documentation? I gave you an exact quote:
> The component instance scope hierarchy extends to out-of-line components, too.

There is an example of 2 different files there as well.

Comment: A .qml is like a factory, ie ListView.qml produces ListView objects when "{}" is used. So the scope of ListView.qml (component) is different from ListView object. The scope refers to the .qml file, not the objects.

Comment: Both links provide the same example which is very different from having 2 .qml. The scope of the instance is different from the scope of the .qml. I had the same confusions at the beginning of my learning of .qml but after stumbling many times I learned to differentiate and understand the scope in QML.

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you please scroll a few lines in the link I sent you? As I said there is an example of two different files. `TitleText.qml` is a child of `TitlePage.qml`, and it can access the `title` property from that file. Even though they are in different files.

Comment: Okay, I understand. What you indicate is valid but in the lines below it indicates that its abuse can be dangerous. That is, if you are going to do something reusable (as it seems that you do a code in your post) then you should not use it:  *Dynamic scoping is very powerful, but it must be used cautiously to prevent the behavior of QML code from becoming difficult to predict. In general it should only be used in cases where the two components are already tightly coupled in another way. When building reusable components, it is preferable to use property interfaces, like this:*

Comment: @eyllanesc I agree with you in general about re-usability. But these (`x_SCALE` and `y_SCALE`) are global properties for scaling the UI that greatly simplify our conversion from design to QML. If I added these as properties to every file it would be way more work and not really make the components that much more usable in my experience since every component in my UI has access to these properties. I would be interested to know how others typically make their UIs scalable but that would be a different question and is not really a problem for me at the moment.

Comment: Recommendation: If you want something to be global then create a singleton: https://wiki.qt.io/Qml_Styling

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks. Yeah I have a TODO to move these to a QML singleton later on.

Comment: I guess that could solve my issue from this question. I have to "drive" those scaling factors from my Main.qml or TestMain.qml. (since they depend on the size of my main window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to missing `QQmlContext`.
I would need to create the QML instance passing the context:

```
item = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(
    component.createWithInitialProperties(
        props,
        engine.contextForObject(wrapper)));
```